# Unicode characters like \u0016 in XML

Tags: xml, unicode

Is there a way to handle unicode characters like \u0016 in XML? As per my understanding, loading such characters in XMLDocument throws an invalid hexadecimal character error. I tried with other unicode characters. They seem to work fine. Only the control characters cause this error. Can we remove these characters without actual parsing the XML?

Comment: Why would you need to use U+0016 in XML? It is a legacy character used for transmission control, not a text character.

Answer (score 27):

> Characters are denoted using the notation used in the Unicode Standard, that is, an optional U+ followed by their hexadecimal number, using at least 4 digits, such as `U+1234` or `U+10FFFD`. In `XML` or HTML this could be expressed as `&#x1234;` or `&#x10FFFD;`.

from [Unicode Technical Report](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Notation).

Valid characters in XML:

> Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

from [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets)

Comment: The fifth edition of version 1.  Bahahahaha!  Sorry, easily amused.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use control characters directly in XML. If you needed to store binary data in XML file you could [Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it. That way you can store images, ...

Comment: Or if they really wanted to encode U+0016 rather than that octet, then something like `<syn/>` to indicate the same semantics.